# Show that $\{[0],[2],[4],[6],[8],[10]\}$ is subgroup of $\Bbb Z_{12}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

I have set $H=\{[0],[2],[4],[6],[8],[10]\}$ and $G=\mathbb Z_{12}$

I will show that H is supgroup of G

Clearly, $H\neq\emptyset$ and $H\subseteq G$

I can write $H=\{m[2] : m \in \mathbb Z\}$

1. I will show that H is closure, let $m_1[2],m_2[2]\in H$,

I've  $m_1[2]+m_2[2]=(m_1+m_2)[2]\in H$

2. I will show that $m_1[2]+(m_2[2])^{-1}\in H$, let $m_1[2],m_2[2]\in H$

I've $m_1[2]+(12-m_2)[2]=(m_1-m_2+12)[2]\in H$

Thus, $H$ is subgroup of $G$

Please check my proof, Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to show by the second paragraph that starts with the word second?

Comment: You can summarize your argument by saying that $H$ is the image of the group homomorphism $m\mapsto m[2]$ from ${\mathbb Z}$ to ${\mathbb Z}_{12}$

Comment: I edited already.

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative proof:

1. $f: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z_{12}$, $f(x)= x \mod 12$ is a group homomorphism.
2. Your subset is a subgroup of the range of $f$ because [your subset is the image of the subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4256109/generalising-22-mathbb-z-mod-12-0-2-4-6-8-10) $22\mathbb Z$ of the domain of $f$.
3. Finally, image of group homomorphism preserves subgroups.