# Generalising $22 \mathbb Z \bmod 12 = \{0,2,4,6,8,10\}$ (subgroup of integers mod integer)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

2 questions

1. $22 \mathbb Z \bmod 12 = \{0,2,4,6,8,10\}$ right? My proof is just: $22(a+6m) \bmod 12$ for each of $a=0,1,2,3,4,5$.
2. If not, then why? If so, then how is this done in general like $n \mathbb Z \mod k$? For that specific case I just did $22m \bmod 12$ for $m=\pm 0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ and then found a pattern. So is it like find a pattern depending on $(n,k)$? Or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula:

$a \mathbb Z \mod b = $ multiples of $d=\gcd(a,b)$ in $\mathbb Z_b$

---

Proof:

Let $a=22$ and $b=12$, let $d=\gcd(a,b)$, so in this case $2$.

Write $d$ as $sa+tb$ and note that $kd = ksa+ktb$ so every multiple of $d \bmod b$ can be found in $a\mathbb Z$.

It follows that we want the multiples of $d$, on the other hand being a multiple of $d$ is clearly a necessity.

Comment: so $a\mathbb Z \mod b$ is multiples of $d=gcd(a,b)$ in $\mathbb Z_b$ ?

Comment: yeah ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: thanks Yorch ! edited your answer to explicitly include the formula

Comment: In fact that's a subset to which any main operation except division is held.